# css li:before with direction from right to left

Tags: css

I wrote some code to remove the decimal point from an ordered list. This is my code:

```
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: level1 
}
ol li:before {
  content: counter(level1) " "; 
  counter-increment: level1;
}
```

it don't show decimal point but the showed number's direction is left to right as below

```
7   xxxxx
8   xxxxx
9   xxxxx
10  xxxxx
11  xxxxx
```

desired result: right to left like notepad++ line numbers

```
 7  xxxxx
 8  xxxxx
 9  xxxxx
10  xxxxx
11  xxxxx
```

i have tried css "direction: rtl" but it not worked.
any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following solution:

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: level1;
}
ol li:before {
  content: counter(level1) "."; 
  counter-increment: level1;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:right;
  min-width:20px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these styles to your `ol li:before` - [Codepen here](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/zoGRwB)

```
ol li:before {
  content: counter(level1) " "; 
  counter-increment: level1;

/* below CSS added */
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  margin-left: -1.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  text-align: right;
  direction: rtl
}
```

You can play around more reading from [this good article](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/color-bullets.en.html)